# Round work space?

Tags: work-environment

What do you call this kind of work space?
Is there a specific name for that round desk? 
What about the chair? It looks like a racing seat.

p.s. These are screenshots from the game "Assassins Creed: Black Flag"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really a question about "the workplace" as we use the phrase here... closer to an interior decorating question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expensive custom surround. "Look at this photo/sketch; I want one of these."

The chair could be any of several high-end ergonomic desk chairs. Start searching catalogs for something that comes close. Or contact the game authors and ask what they used.